# I Cant get Ruby Packer to work and need a method to package a Ruby application

Tags: ruby

I have a ruby script that I run from the terminal, however I want to be able to double-click an icon like I would an application and run the script. I've looked at ruby-packer, but it isn't working for me.

What is the best option to accomplish this?

Im on a mac.

In terminal, I'm not at the directory of the .rb file because when I try to run `./rubyc` from the directory containing the .rb file, I get the error `command not recognized`

When I run `./rubyc /RubyProjects/signOff.rb /signOff.out` I'm able to get it to run, but the outfile file is called `rubyc` that just re-runs the same code when I double-click it. I'm at a loss for how to get it to work properly.
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-o` parameter defines the output filename:

```
rubyc -o signOff signOff.rb
```